# Decimal Field Data Validation using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a task to validate/Data cleansing of decimal field I am creating file as data frame and passing decimal column for validation .

```
SAMPLEINPUTCOLUMN
0.1
NA
123-
.54
Null
text123test
3453$
test123.49


EXPECTEDOUTPUT
0.1
0
-123
0.54
0
123
3453
123.49

object decimalfieldvalidation {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("Decimal Field Validation").getOrCreate()

   val sourcefile = spark.read.textFile("C:/Users/phadpa01/Desktop/InputFiles/decimal.csv").filter(!_.isEmpty).toDF("DECIMALFIELD")

  val updatedDf = sourcefile.withColumn("DECIMALFIELD", regexp_replace(col("DECIMALFIELD"), "#N/A", "0"))

  val updatedDf1 = updatedDf.withColumn("DECIMALFIELD", regexp_replace(col("DECIMALFIELD"), "NA", "0"))
}
}
```

I am replacing each value individually. Kindly help me on this.

Regards,

Pravin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you know how to read your `textfile` and convert it to `dataframe`

As explained in the `OP` that you have a `column` in your `dataframe` as

```
+-----------------+
|SAMPLEINPUTCOLUMN|
+-----------------+
|0.1              |
|NA               |
|123-             |
|.54              |
|Null             |
|text123test      |
|3453$            |
|test123.49       |
+-----------------+
```

And you are trying to `validate` the `decimals` and extracting them in that `column`. If thats the required condition then a simple `udf` function should solve your issue.

Define the `udf` function as

```
def regexp_replace = udf((value: String) => {
  val decimal = value.replaceAll("[A-Za-z$]", "")
  if(decimal.isEmpty){
    0.toDouble
  }
  else{
    if(decimal.last.equals('-')){
      -decimal.replaceAll("[-]", "").toDouble
    }
    else {
      decimal.toDouble
    }
  }
})
```

Now all you have to do is call the `udf` function using `withColumn`

```
dataframe.withColumn("SAMPLEINPUTCOLUMN", regexp_replace(col("SAMPLEINPUTCOLUMN"))).show(false)
```

You will have the following output

```
+-----------------+
|SAMPLEINPUTCOLUMN|
+-----------------+
|0.1              |
|0.0              |
|-123.0           |
|0.54             |
|0.0              |
|123.0            |
|3453.0           |
|123.49           |
+-----------------+
```

I guess thats what is required.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. If it really helped you then upvote as well please :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.I need one more suggestion. Actually I am building generic code which can validate any decimal fields from file. like which can identify the type of column and apply this logic to validate decimal field.

Comment: "ID:int,Payment1:decimal,Name:string,Payment2:decimal,address:string,Payment3:decimal." Code has to pick dynamically decimal column based on data type Payment1,Payment2,Payment3 and apply this logic to validate the decimal field.

Comment: Kindly suggest on this.

Comment: For that, make a list of column names from schema whose dataType is Double(Decimal). Then just use select query.

Comment: I have done up to this I need help to pick only double type columns."ID:int,PAYMENT1:double,NAME:string,PAYMENT2:double,ADDRESS:string,PAYMENT3:double". like PAYMENT1,PAYMENT2,PAYMENT3 from these string based double data type.

Comment: You will have to post another question with the requirement, the sample table, schema and expected output as I am not understanding. :)

Comment: I dont have access to place new question

Comment: "ID:int,PAYMENT1:double,NAME:string,PAYMENT2:double,‌​ADDRESS:string,PAYME‌​NT3:double" ----------from this string I need to extract only PAYMENT1,PAYMENT2,PAYMENT3 columns.

Comment: you can always ask as many questions as you want. you don't need access. do you?

Comment: question limit exceeded. :(.    I joined recently in stack

Comment: really? sorry . Ok . Can you share me printSchema() output?

Comment: "ID:int,PAYMENT1:double,NAME:string,PAYMENT2:double,ADDRESS:string,PAYMENT3:double"  I want to select whose datatype has double.

Comment: there are 1000 columns I need to select only those column whose data type has double

Comment: from above I want only "PAYMENT1,PAYMENT2,PAYMENT3"

Comment: if you want only `PAYMENT1,PAYMENT2,PAYMENT3` then apply `dataframe.select("PAYMENT1", "PAYMENT2", "PAYMENT3")`

Comment: its become generic. I want to make it dynamic.I want a query to select column whose data type is double

Comment: try `    val select = dataframe.schema.filter(_.dataType == DoubleType).map(_.name)
    dataframe.select(select.map(col): _*).show`

Comment: Hi I am done with automation part. there is two more validation I need to add on same udf.

Comment: abc123.12abc123 => 123.12 |||||||| 123.12abc123 => 123.12|||||abc123.12=> 123.12. I need regex to find anly first match of integer value.

Comment: comments are getting too long. you need post another question for it. If I happen to see it I will answer it :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390726/decimal-validation-with-scala

Comment: Hello Ramesh. I am using merge command but facing error like Unkonwn command:merge "java -jar /home/phadpa01/Scala_Code/parquet-tools-1.8.0.jar merge /home/phadpa01/Scala_Code/op /home/phadpa01/op/test.parquet"

Comment: It should have been a new question. Did you try https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools?